# Failed connection to MySQL database

Tags: php

I've just bought my first domain and hosting with godaddy. Im using a mysqli_connect script thats refuses to connect to my database which is set to receive remote connections as well.

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connect('www.makleaks.com', 'db_username', 'db_users_password', 'db');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error;
    exit();
?>
```

Anyone please help?

Comment: Try changing 'www.makleaks.com' to 'localhost'

Comment: wow... that worked! But how??

Comment: it's probable that the mysql server only allows connections through localhost. This is a security feature, otherwise anyone on the internet could try to get in.

Comment: Okk... im also new to stackoverflow. Its kinda scary how you guys know so much. Was it wise for me to post my website's domain with some of the php script Im using for it? Can someone do some bad stuff to my site by knowing just those few lines of code?

Comment: Not from that code above, unless your username and password is literally 'db_users_password'. All you gave was a domain name. The worst that will probably happen is that you'll get some extra traffic. The post may be edited to avoid any claims of sneaky advertising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SQL server is located in the same server as your web host, then try:

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_users_password', 'db');
```